How to find all AzureOpenAI deployments with an API key
I use LangChain to interact with the company models hosted on Azure.
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
    openai_api_key=OPENAI_APIKEY,
    azure_endpoint='...',
    azure_deployment='..',)

There are multiple models deployed, with different specs.
I was wondering if I can list all the available deployments using LangChain or OAI, based only on the API key.
The following code snippet throws a ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED], but AzureChatOpenAI is working fine with the same API key.
import openai
openai.api_key = OPENAI_APIKEY

# Call the OpenAI API to get a list of available models
# response = openai.ChatCompletion.list_models()
models = openai.models.list()


# Print the names of all available models
for model in models:
    print(model['name'])

Does LangChain have a similar function, or is there a workaround?
